# Parallel execution of goroutine query in gorm.io/gorm does not work

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have 2 entities:

```golang
type Service struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
}

type ConnectedService struct {
    ID        int
    ServiceID string
    Service   Service
}
```

I want to get the associated Service entity when I get the ConnectedService.
In gorm.v1 everything worked, in the new version of gorm.v2, when I try to make a request in parallel threads, I get the error:

```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "connected_services" (SQLSTATE 42P01)
[4.020ms] [rows:0] SELECT "connected_services"."id","connected_services"."service_id" FROM "connected_services" Service WHERE "connected_services"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "connected_services"."id" LIMIT 1
FATA[0000] ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "connected_services" (SQLSTATE 42P01)
```

This is due to the fact that gorm.v2 added contexts and sessions to requests:

```
Method Chain Safety/Goroutine Safety
To reduce GC allocs, GORM V2 will share Statement when using method chains, and will only create new Statement instances for new initialized *gorm.DB or after a New Session Method, to reuse a *gorm.DB, you need to make sure it just after a New Session Method, for example:
```

But I can't do it. Method for getting connected service:

```golang
type Repository struct { db *gorm.DB }
func (r *Repository) GetConnectedService(id int) (*ConnectedService, error) {
    cs := &ConnectedService{}
    if err := r.db.WithContext(context.Background()).Joins("Service").First(cs, id).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return cs, nil
}
```

Init db and repository:

```golang
func main() {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=localhost port=5433 user=guest password=guest dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")
    db, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    repo := &Repository{db: db}
    . . .
}
```

I call it like this:

```golang
import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {
    . . .
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            cs, err := repo.GetConnectedService(i)
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Errorf("get connected service: %s", err.Error())
                return
            }
            logrus.Printf("%+v", cs)
        }(i)
    }
    . . .
}
```

Without <.Joins("Service")> everything works fine, but as soon as we add this, an error crashes.

Comment: How do you initialize your `r.db`? Make sure to pass the database name in the connection string.

Comment: The connection is standard. There are no problems with him, everything works.
The problem comes up when I try to execute .Joins("Service") in parallel calls (at the same time).
If done sequentially, everything is done.

Comment: Arn't you sharing DB connection in this case?

Comment: UPD. Updated the description, maybe it will become clearer.

Comment: i have a similar issue. did you fix your problem?